# Expectation of $\left| X - a \right|$ and the generator of Hermite polynomials

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, hermite-polynomials

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ with an unknown distribution, but known first $N$ moments $\left\{ E [ X^n] \right\}_{n=1}^N$. We are asked to calculate the value of
\begin{equation}
E \left[ | X - a | \right]
\end{equation}
where $X > 0$ a.s. and $a>0$.

My idea to attack this problem is as follows:

An integral representation of the square root function is
$$
\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty \, \frac{1 -  e^{-zx} }{ z^{3/2} } \, dz
$$
The expectation of the absolute value can be written as
\begin{equation}
\label{expabs}
E \left[ | X - a | \right] = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty \, \frac{1 - E \left[ e^{-z(X - a)^2 } \right] }{ z^{3/2} } \, dz
\end{equation}

Now
\begin{equation}
e^{-z(X - a)^2} = e^{ - (a\sqrt z)^2} e^{ - (X\sqrt z)^2 + 2(a\sqrt z)(X\sqrt z)} 
\end{equation}
We recognize $ e^{ - (X\sqrt z)^2 + 2(a\sqrt z)(X\sqrt z)}$ as the generating function of Hermite polynomials. That is,
\begin{equation}
\label{Hgen}
e^{ - (X\sqrt z)^2 + 2(a\sqrt z)(X\sqrt z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ H_n(a\sqrt z) }{ n!}  (X\sqrt z)^n
\end{equation}
where the Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$ are given by
\begin{equation}
H_n(y) = \sum_{k=0}^{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor } \frac{ (-1)^k n! }{ k! (n-2k)! } (2y)^{n-2k}
\end{equation}
and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

Thus we can, in principle, calculate the expectation $E \left[ | X - a | \right]$ because
\begin{align}
E \left[ e^{-z(X - a)^2 } \right] &= e^{ - (a\sqrt z)^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ H_n(a\sqrt z) }{ n!}  E \left[ (X\sqrt z)^n \right] \nonumber \\
&\approx e^{ - (a\sqrt z)^2} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{ H_n(a\sqrt z) }{ n!}  E \left[ (X\sqrt z)^n \right] 
\end{align}

**My question:**

1. Is the above derivation free of error(s)?
2. What are the necessary condition(s) for the above series, or a truncated to finite N-terms, in terms of Hermite polynomials to converge?